# No compila mi aplicación con spring nativo y mybatis

Tags: spring

Estoy migrando mi proyecto spring a modo nativo y localmente me levanta el proyecto y me llegan a responde los métodos, pero al intentar ejecutar con un docker run la imagen que cree mediante -Pnative spring-boot:build-image me arroja el error que muestro a continuación
[image: Imagen al ejecutar el docker run]
Estoy utilizando:

```
 - artifactId:spring-boot-starter-parent version:3.1.4
 - artifactId:mybatis-spring-boot-starter version:3.0.2
```

Con

```
java 17.0.9 2023-10-17 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 17.0.9+11.1 (build 17.0.9+11-LTS-jvmci-23.0-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 17.0.9+11.1 (build 17.0.9+11-LTS-jvmci-23.0-b21, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Agradecería la ayuda

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.